# Rank-related tags are an enormous mess

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-reorganization

We have the following rank-related tags:

- [mann-whitney-u-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mann-whitney-u-test) (271) -- ranksum test
- [wilcoxon](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wilcoxon) (297) -- used for ranksum and for signed-rank
- [signed-rank-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/signed-rank-test) (37)
- [sign-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sign-test) (21)
- [spearman](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spearman) (134)
- [spearman-rho](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spearman-rho) (107)
- [kendall-tau](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kendall-tau) (74)
- [rank-correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rank-correlation) (101) -- most questions seem to be about Spearman's rho
- [ranking](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ranking) (357)
- [ranks](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ranks) (70)

**Problems:**

1. <strike>`[wilcoxon]` is ambiguous. Worse, one meaning of `[wilcoxon]` is synonymous with `[mann-whitney-u-test]` and another meaning is synonymous with `[signed-rank-test]`.</strike>
2. <strike>`[spearman]` and `[spearman-rho]` are synonymous.</strike>
3. <strike>`[rank-correlation]` might be better off sorted out into specific types.</strike>
4. `[ranking]` and `[ranks]` have somewhat unclear scope.

---

**My current proposal is:**

1. <strike>Create `[wilcoxon-rank-sum]` and `[wilcoxon-signed-rank]` tags.</strike> **Done.**
2. <strike>Make `[wilcoxon-rank-sum]` and `[mann-whitney-u-test]` both synonyms of `[wilcoxon-mann-whitney]`.</strike> **Done by @Glen_b.**
3. <strike>Make `[wilcoxon-signed-rank]` the synonym of `[signed-rank-test]`.</strike> **Done by @Glen_b. Later reverted by @Scortchi, following @ttnphns' answer.**
4. <strike>Go through all `[wilcoxon]` questions and move those about rank sum into `[wilcoxon-mann-whitney]`.</strike> **Done by @mdewey.**
5. <strike>Move all the remaining threads from `[wilcoxon]` into `[signed-rank-test]` via mod merge hammer.</strike> **Done by @Glen_b.**
6. <strike>Merge `[spearman]` into `[spearman-rho]`.</strike> **Synonym created via voting. Merge done by @Glen_b.**
7. <strike>Sort as many questions as possible from `[rank-correlation]` into `[spearman-rho]` and/or `[kendall-tau]` and/or `[goodman-kruskal-gamma]`. It looks like there will be ~30 questions left though.</strike> **Done. Thanks @mdewey.**
8. Go through `[ranking]` and `[ranks]` and try to understand what to do with them. I leave this open for now because this involves 400+ threads.

Comment: +1 Good suggestions all over. Especially the [tag:Wilcoxon] is necessary because it clearly misleading users substantially. Would you make [rank] and [ranking] synonyms?

Comment: Given the confusion generated by `[wilcoxon]`, I wonder if it would be better not to make it a synonym, but just to destroy it. I don't know. My thought is that someone might still come along later & type that & automatically get the one synonym, when they had meant the other.

Comment: @gung, I think we should treat [wilcoxon] similar to [student-t]. I would create two new tags [wilcoxon-ranksum] and [wilcoxon-signed-rank], then go through all threads in [wilcoxon] and sort them out into these two, and finally make [wilcoxon-ranksum] a synonym of [ranksum] (together with [mann-whitney-u-test]; the master thread name can be discussed though) and [wilcoxon-signed-rank] a synonym of [signed-rank]. I don't think we will need to blacklist [wilcoxon] after that.

Comment: @usεr11852, I *guess* that [rank] can be a synonym of [ranking], but somebody has to look at these tags in more detail to see if it makes sense. I am not sure we need a ranking tag on questions about ranksum test or spearman's correlation; this seems superfluous. So I have a feeling that in many cases it can be removed altogether (or replaced by a more specific tag). But there probably are some general questions on ranking or rank-based methods for which the tag would make sense.

Comment: Some good suggestions here. If I recall correctly, "Spearman rho" and "Kendall tau" are far from the only type of rank correlation though, so I don't think it is so easy to get rid of "rank correlation" so easily.

Comment: Would you say that these tags are... *rank*?

Comment: @user777 Had to consult the dictionary to get the joke :-) Thanks.

Comment: @amoeba, voted.

Comment: I am working my way through rank-correlation. I have done all the easy ones. One thing I notice is that there are some about rank biserial correlation. We have no tag for biserial correlation and there are about 35+ questions about it. Shall I create it and tag them? Should I do this as a separate proposal?

Comment: @mdewey To be honest, I've never heard about "biserial correlation" before. Do you mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient? The article says "The point-biserial correlation is mathematically equivalent to the Pearson (product moment) correlation". If this is true, then I guess the existing [pearson-r] tag is enough, isn't it?

Comment: `ranking` is the task for a respondent to rank stimuli (i.e. it is distinquished from `rating`  or `labeling`/`categorizing`. `ranks` are transformed, ranked values.

Comment: @mdewey By the way, what are you doing with rank-correlation questions that do not mention any specific type of rank correlation (Spearman/Kendall/etc)? Are there many questions like that?

Comment: I am doing them on an ad hoc basis. Some of them are not really about rank correlation at all. There will be a few left which have totally defeated me and I will let you lnow when I have to show the white flag.

Comment: I think that `rank-correlation` tag has rights to exist. There are rank-based correlations apart from Spearman or Kendall. Perhaps, we might consider to rename that tag to more general but close `nonparametric-correlation` tag.

Comment: @ttnphns It's just the usual problem with the subset tags... We have 250 Qs in spearman-rho, around 80 in kendall-tau, 3 questions in goodman-kruskall-gamma, so it's 300+ questions *about* rank correlation *without* rank-correlation tag. So having a separate general rank-correlation tag with only a few threads (currently only 10) is just not very helpful for navigation.

Comment: I have now reduced rank-correlation to a handful. These are ones where I really do not see what the best course of action might be and would welcom someone else having a go. The ones I eliminated were mostly spearman-rho, some kendall-tau, and a mixture of other statistics which were not really rank-correlation at all IMHO. In the process I created a tag somers-d with a wiki. There are a few more Somers'  D questions which I shall find and tag but they did not have rank-correlation.

Comment: @ttnphns you are of course right but if people ask about those other methods then they can either use both the tags correlation and nonparametric together or create a new tag (for instance for Spearman's footrule)

Comment: @mdewey There are only 2 closed questions left in rank-correlation, so it should disappear after the questions are deleted (I think it's 9 days after closure so still in a couple of days). Now we will have to sort out [wilcoxon]...

Comment: I was wondering what was still left on the agenda

Comment: Is there an update on [wilcoxon] progress and hints about what help is needed at this stage?

Comment: @mdewey I don't know. I was not working on it (I am not doing much here these days). I see that it has 215 Qs now, so quite a bit has been eliminated but I am not sure by whom. In any case, the plan is still (as per #5) to manually re-tag everything about ranksum test (Mann-Whitney / Wilcoxon ranksum) into wilcoxon-mann-whitney.

Comment: I think most of them are due to me. I will have a look at some of the others starting from the oldest.

Answer (score 5):

### Signed-rank-test to Wilcoxon-signed-rank test

[This answer was originally posted as a separate [question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4680/3277) (you still can see comments there) and now transferred to here as an answer. It is my request about the *tags* of two "Wilcoxon" tests, independent-sample and paired-sample.]

Moderators, please rename tag `signed-rank-test` (Wilcoxon paired sample test) to `wilcoxon-signed-rank`. We have curently such tag, but it is a junior synonym of `signed-rank-test`. So, please appoint `wilcoxon-signed-rank` to be the main tag and `signed-rank-test` its junior synonym: revert.

For the unpaired Wilcoxon, we have nice tag `wilcoxon-mann-whitney`. Thence it is logical to have `wilcoxon-signed-rank` as its paired counterpart.

Note that `signed-rank-test` *isn't optimal* because it doesn't mention "Wilcoxon". It thus can be confused with the sign test. Besides, there exist other, less known, rank tests based on signs of the rank differences, which adds to the confusion. Finally, a number of software (SPSS for example) and books use name "Wilcoxon" *only* with the paired signed-rank test and never with the unpaired test which they call "Mann-Whitney"; it might be an argument to state that "Wilcoxon" have stronger - at least not lesser - belonging to the paired test than to the unpaired and therefore should be included into the tag of the paired test.

An alternative name: create `wilcoxon-paired-test` instead of `wilcoxon-signed-rank`, if you would like it better. I like both variants of the tag name.

Comment: As I said elsewhere, the direction of a tag synonym (once the tags are merged, as these two are) makes almost zero practical difference. It's mostly a question of what tag name we like more. I don't have any strong opinion here, and I am certainly fine with doing the reversal that you suggest. Perhaps you are right and it will make more sense like that. The synonym was originally created this way simply because signed-rank-test was already an existing tag, there was no other reason.

Comment: @amoeba, thank you for reply and clarification, and for potential agreement. I hope that my arguments in the answer could weigh sufficiently to do the re-tagging. Both tags ought to start with `wilcoxon...`, for me. (Thank you for creating the very topical thread on ranks.)

Comment: I've swapped the tag names so that `wilcoxon-signed-rank` is now the synonym.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** the [wilcoxon](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wilcoxon) tag now only contains tags which can be mapped to [wilcoxon-signed-rank](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wilcoxon-signed-rank) so if any moderator is reading this can they please carry out the merge operation mentioned by Amoeba in the original question.

**Longer version**

There were a few which did not map oonto [wilcoxon-mann-whitney] which I have re-tagged appropriately. One remaining issue is that there was one about the Wilcoxon-Gehan method. I have temporarily created the obvious tag for it. We have a handful of other questions which could be re-tagged to that tag. Shall I do that and provide a wiki for it or is there some other existing tag which could be used? I have an unmet training need for time-to-event analysis so would welcome second opinions here.

---

The remaining issue, as far as I can tell, is the [ranking] and [ranks] tags. My personal view is that there are too many of these to make a thorough examination of each one a viable proposition.

Comment: There might be a few left over threads, at least I find several with the following searches: http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bwilcoxon%5D+%22rank+sum%22+is%3Aquestion (3 Qs), http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bwilcoxon%5D+%22whitney%22+is%3Aquestion (2 Qs), http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bwilcoxon%5D+%22mann%22+is%3Aquestion (1 more Q). I did not look into them (yet), but some of them might need retagging too.

Comment: Re Wilcoxon-Gehan, I know nothing about it, but this search http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Wilcoxon+Gehan+is%3Aquestion (only 5 Qs mentioning Wilcoxon and Gehan) suggests that this tag is not much needed. Perhaps tagging with [survival] is enough?

Comment: As far as your left over ones are concerned I think many of these are in fact signed ranks even if they speak about rank sum. I suppose I could double tag them which is what I did with some of the others.

Comment: I am somewhat reluctant to have `[wilcoxon]` made a synonym of `wmw`, in that `w` could be used for a number of things. In the future, new or careless users will type `w` for what they want (something else) & then it will be mapped to `wmw` & thus mistagged. W/ 129 remaining, it's a heavy lift, but I wonder if manually retagging them & letting `w` die might be preferable.

Comment: @gung in fact the remaining ones are supposed to be wilcoxon signed ranks but I take your point. I think the safest thing is to do them manually. It is only 129 whereas there were nearly 300 so will not take many days to achieve.

Comment: I have now re-tagged the Wilcoxon-Gehan one with [survival].

Comment: @gung The idea is *not* to make [w] the synonym of [wsr]. The idea is to transfer all threads from [w] to [wsr] via tag merge and then to delete [w] tag altogether.

Comment: @amoeba, my mistake. That's a fine solution, IMO.

Comment: I looked at the threads I linked above and I agree they are all about signed-rank. I'd say we can go ahead with the merge.

Comment: I merged as requested. There were a few threads that looked kind of borderline so if you see any that should have the WMW tag please add it.

Comment: @Glen_b and mdewey: Thanks. I leave this thread open for the time being, because I am not sure what's the decision should be regarding [ranking]+[ranks]. Should they be synonymized? Should they be split into sub-tags? Should we leave them as is? What are these two tags even about, are they all about rank-based tests & rank-based correlations (what's the common term for that?), or are there other topics in these tags?

Comment: "ranking" could be relevant to more than just rank based tests and correlations but if in practice it isn't used for anything else that's fine. I don't know that the two should necessarily be covered by a single term.